# ctypes segfault on OSX only

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, ctypes, language-binding

I created a very simple C library binding in Python using ctypes. All it does is accept a string and return a string.

I did the development on Ubuntu, and everything looked fine. Unfortunately, on OSX the exact same code fails. I'm completely stumped.

I've put together a minimal case showing the issue I'm having.

#### main.py

```
import ctypes

# Compile for:
#   Linux: `gcc -fPIC -shared hello.c -o hello.so`
#   OSX:   `gcc -shared hello.c -o hello.so`
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./hello.so')

# Call the library
ptr = lib.hello("Frank")
data = ctypes.c_char_p(ptr).value # segfault here on OSX only
lib.free_response(ptr)

# Prove it worked
print data
```

#### hello.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// This is the actual binding call.
char* hello(char* name) {
    char* response = malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    strcpy(response, "Hello, ");
    strcat(response, name);
    strcat(response, "!\n");
    return response;
}

// This frees the response memory and must be called by the binding.
void free_response(char *ptr) { free(ptr); }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify the return type of your function. Specifically, declare it to be `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)`.

```
import ctypes

lib = ctypes.CDLL('./hello.so')    
lib.hello.restype = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char)

ptr = lib.hello("Frank")
print repr(ctypes.cast(ptr, ctypes.c_char_p).value)
lib.free_response(ptr)
```

Comment: Wow, it works like a charm. Any thoughts on why it works on Linux but not OSX? I personally like the simplicity of the code I had previously.

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall did you compile it as 64 bits under Linux too ? The edited code is just as simple.

Comment: I'm not sure what architecture I compiled it as. I'm just using the default python and gcc, if that helps.

Comment: Well, either way, your edited code is just as simple as my original. Thanks a million!