# Memory leak in a C-Python wrapper

Tags: python, c, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, ctypes

I have more than 100k iterations calling one C function, and running the profiler I see +25 Mb for each call of that function.

Result is not cumulative so Memory allocation must not be cumulative, otherwise it is a memory leak (I output after each call to a file).

I already saw how one can free variables in C, with `py_decref` before returning. But in my case, and the way algorithm was built, I have no return variable, but pointers as parameters that are useful in return to Python code in each iteration.

With my basic C language knowledge, I tried turning the parameters to return values without succeeding.

Here is the declaration of parameters and the call:

My C lib is Illumination:

```
Illumination.restype = None
Illumination.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
                         ndpointer(ctypes.c_float),
                         ndpointer(ctypes.c_int)]
```

All intermediate variables in Illumination are freed simply using `free`.

Function in C is:

```
void Illumination(double Longitude, double Latitude, float *fact_sun, int *nb_nodes)
```

I already played on type like double to float hopefully results will be concise later but it did not help with the memory leak.

`ctypes._reset_cache()` and `gc.collect()` did not help anywhere in the loop or in the script in general.

To my understanding I need to deal with it in Python. Sadly I don't know how.

Profiling result is

```
Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurences   Line Contents
============================================================
    30  106.109 MiB  106.109 MiB           1   @profile
    31                                         def my_func():
    32                                         
    33                                             # C Illumination function from shared file Illumination.so
    34                                         
    35  106.242 MiB    0.133 MiB           1       lib = ctypes.CDLL('Illumination.so')
    36  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       Illumination = lib.Illumination
    37  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       Illumination.restype = None
    38  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       Illumination.argtypes = [ctypes.c_double, ctypes.c_double,
    39  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                                ndpointer(ctypes.c_float),
    40  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                                ndpointer(ctypes.c_int)]
    41                                         
    42  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       start_time = time.time()
    43                                         
    44                                             # @profile
    45                                             # #############################################################################################################
    46                                             # variable initialization and declaration
    47                                             # #############################################################################################################
    48                                             # PATHNAMES
    49                                         
    50  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       SHAPE_MODEL_PATHNAME = 'fac_ets.obj'
    51  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       BARYCENTER_PATHNAME = 'bar_ycen.txt'
    52                                             SS_COORD_PATHNAME = \
    53  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           'SS_coord/sb_lonlat_ort.txt'
    54                                         
    55                                             # 20201001174159.txt: Dt 3h old kernel | 20201014151855_1styear.txt: 25min
    56                                             # 25_11_20.txt new kernel, dt=24,min
    57                                             # lonlat_27_11_20_1ort_3h : Dt 3h new kernel
    58                                         
    59  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       SH_FACET_PATHNAME = 'self_illu_facets/'
    60                                         
    61                                             # facets_SH_geometry old folder
    62                                         
    63                                             # facets_SH = pd.DataFrame(genfromtxt("facets_SH.txt"))[0].astype(np.int)
    64                                         
    65                                             # SHAPE MODEL AND  DX RESOLUTION
    66                                         
    67  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       nb_face = 124938  # number of facets in shape model
    68  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       nb_node = 62471  # number of nodes in shape model
    69  106.242 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       nb_pts = 1  # & 18817 old kernel | 136346 & 18796 new kernel
    70                                         
    71                                             # #  LONGITUDE AND LATITUDE
    72                                         
    73  115.289 MiB    9.047 MiB           1       lon_lat_dH = genfromtxt(SS_COORD_PATHNAME)
    74  115.289 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       lon_lat_dH = pd.DataFrame(lon_lat_dH)
    75                                         
    76                                             # if we read it from spice data file (ignore date and distance)
    77                                         
    78  115.289 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       Longitude = lon_lat_dH[3]
    79  115.883 MiB    0.594 MiB           1       Latitude = 90 - lon_lat_dH[4]
    80  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       dH = lon_lat_dH[6] * 6.684587e-9  # 1.496e-8
    81                                         
    82                                             # constants for energy equations
    83                                         
    84  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       F = 1368  #  constant
    85  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       sigma = 5.67E-8  # stefan-boltzman constant
    86  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       albedo = 0.06  # geometric albedo
    87  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       albedo_bond = 0.04  # bond albedo
    88  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       emiss = 0.95  # emissivity
    89  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       inv_pi = 1 / pi
    90  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       fact_SH_VIS = F * albedo * inv_pi
    91  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       fact_T = (1 - albedo_bond) * F / (emiss * sigma)
    92  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       fact_SH_IR = emiss * sigma * inv_pi
    93                                         
    94  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       facets_selection = [44248]  # 44247,44248
    95                                         
    96                                             # 25821,119166-119167,35730-35731,43638,119147
    97                                         
    98  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           2       for facet in facets_selection:
    99                                         
   100  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           facet_i = facet
   101                                                 OUTPUT_PATHNAME = \
   102                                                     'flux_outputs/flux_new_kernel/region8' \
   103  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               + str(facet_i) + 'testProfiler.txt'
   104                                         
   105                                                 # variables for illumination geometry
   106                                         
   107  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           cos_Illumination = np.empty(nb_face, dtype=np.float32)  # # float32 ## added
   108  115.883 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           nb_node_Illumination = np.empty(nb_face, dtype=np.int32)  # # int8 ## added
   109                                         
   110                                                 # variables for geometry of self-heating (cosz2)
   111                                         
   112  116.387 MiB    0.504 MiB           1           cos_alpha = [None] * nb_face
   113  117.418 MiB    1.031 MiB           1           angle_solid = [None] * nb_face
   114  118.449 MiB    1.031 MiB           1           factor = [None] * nb_face
   115                                         
   116                                                 # #############################################################################################################
   117                                                 # SELF-HEATING GEOMETRY
   118                                                 # #############################################################################################################
   119                                         
   120                                                 # READING DATA OF SELF-HEATING GEOMETRY
   121                                         
   122  127.465 MiB    9.016 MiB           1           Nod_coord = genfromtxt(SHAPE_MODEL_PATHNAME)
   123  127.465 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           Nod_coord = pd.DataFrame(Nod_coord)
   124  127.465 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           x_node = (Nod_coord[1])[0:nb_node].tolist()
   125  127.465 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           y_node = (Nod_coord[2])[0:nb_node].tolist()
   126  127.773 MiB    0.309 MiB           1           z_node = (Nod_coord[3])[0:nb_node].tolist()
   127  127.773 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           i_f = np.asarray((Nod_coord[1])[nb_node:nb_face
   128  128.801 MiB    1.027 MiB           1                            + nb_node]).astype(int) - 1
   129  128.801 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           j_f = np.asarray((Nod_coord[2])[nb_node:nb_face
   130  129.840 MiB    1.039 MiB           1                            + nb_node]).astype(int) - 1
   131  129.840 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           k_f = np.asarray((Nod_coord[3])[nb_node:nb_face
   132  130.871 MiB    1.031 MiB           1                            + nb_node]).astype(int) - 1
   133  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           m = [i_f[facet_i], j_f[facet_i], k_f[facet_i]]
   134  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node1 = np.array([x_node[m[0]], y_node[m[0]], z_node[m[0]]])
   135  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node2 = np.array([x_node[m[1]], y_node[m[1]], z_node[m[1]]])
   136  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node3 = np.array([x_node[m[2]], y_node[m[2]], z_node[m[2]]])
   137  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node1_node2 = np.array([node2[0] - node1[0], node2[1]
   138  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                                  - node1[1], node2[2] - node1[2]])
   139  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node1_node3 = np.array([node3[0] - node1[0], node3[1]
   140  130.871 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                                  - node1[1], node3[2] - node1[2]])
   141                                         
   142                                                 # READING FACETS BARYCENTER DATA
   143                                         
   144  138.703 MiB    7.832 MiB           1           barycenter = genfromtxt(BARYCENTER_PATHNAME)
   145  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           barycenter = pd.DataFrame(barycenter)
   146  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           x_bary = barycenter[1]
   147  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           y_bary = barycenter[2]
   148  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           z_bary = barycenter[3]
   149                                         
   150                                                 # NORMAL VECTOR OF the FACET
   151                                         
   152  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           vect_a = np.cross(node1_node2, node1_node3)
   153                                         
   154                                                 # SH      = genfromtxt('output.txt')
   155                                         
   156  138.703 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           SH = genfromtxt(glob.glob(SH_FACET_PATHNAME + '*'
   157  143.492 MiB    4.789 MiB           1                           + str(facet_i) + '.txt')[0])
   158  143.492 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           SH = pd.DataFrame(SH)
   159  143.492 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           S_facet = SH[0]
   160  143.492 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           cos_SH = SH[1]
   161  143.492 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           node_SH = SH[2]
   162  143.492 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           x = SH[3]
   163                                         
   164                                                 # SOLID ANGLE
   165                                         
   166  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB      124939           for l in range(nb_face):
   167  153.730 MiB    4.891 MiB      124938               if node_SH[l] != 3 or x[l] == 0:
   168  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB      124520                   factor[l] = 0
   169                                                     else:
   170                                         
   171                                                     # vector facet->facet_x
   172                                         
   173  153.730 MiB    4.867 MiB         418                   vect_b = np.array([x_bary[l] - x_bary[facet_i],
   174  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         418                                     y_bary[l] - y_bary[facet_i],
   175  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         418                                     z_bary[l] - z_bary[facet_i]])
   176  153.730 MiB    0.480 MiB         418                   if np.linalg.norm(vect_b) == 0:
   177  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                       factor[l] = 0
   178                                                         else:
   179  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                       cos_alpha[l] = np.vdot(vect_a, vect_b) \
   180  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                           / (np.linalg.norm(vect_a)
   181  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                              * np.linalg.norm(vect_b))
   182  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                       if cos_alpha[l] <= 0:
   183                                                                 factor[l] = 0
   184                                                             else:
   185                                                                 factor[l] = cos_SH[l] * cos_alpha[l] \
   186  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                               * S_facet[l] / (np.linalg.norm(vect_b)
   187  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                                   * np.linalg.norm(vect_b))
   188  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB         418                   del vect_b  # ###added
   189  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB      124938               ctypes._reset_cache()
   190                                                 # #############################################################################################################
   191                                                 # energy flux calculations
   192                                                 # #############################################################################################################
   193                                         
   194  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           SH = 0
   195  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           flux_neighbor_VIS = 0
   196  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           flux_neighbor_IR = 0
   197                                         
   198                                                 # opening output file to write
   199                                         
   200  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           file = open(OUTPUT_PATHNAME, 'w')
   201                                         
   202                                                 # file2 = open(OUTPUT_PATHNAME, 'w')
   203                                         
   204  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           2           for i in range(nb_pts):
   205                                         
   206  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               VIS = 0.0
   207  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               IR = 0.0
   208                                         
   209  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               inv_dH_sqr = 1 / (dH[i] * dH[i])
   210                                         
   211  153.730 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               Illumination(Longitude[i], Latitude[i], cos_Illumination,
   212  180.023 MiB   26.293 MiB           1                            nb_node_Illumination)
   213  180.023 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               if i % 1000 == 0:
   214  179.820 MiB   -0.203 MiB           1                   gc.collect()  # ##added
   215  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124939               for l in range(nb_face):
   216  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124938                   if nb_node_Illumination[l] != 3 or cos_Illumination[l] \
   217  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB       42745                       < 0:
   218  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB       82193                       cos_Illumination[l] = 0
   219                                         
   220  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124938                   if l == facet_i or factor[l] == 0:
   221  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124521                       flux_neighbor_VIS = 0
   222  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124521                       flux_neighbor_IR = 0
   223                                                         else:
   224                                                             flux_neighbor_VIS = cos_Illumination[l] * factor[l] \
   225  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                           * fact_SH_VIS * inv_dH_sqr
   226  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                       T_neighbor_4 = max(fact_T * cos_Illumination[l]
   227  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                               * inv_dH_sqr, 160000)  # 30**4, 40k
   228                                                             flux_neighbor_IR = fact_SH_IR * factor[l] \
   229  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB         417                           * T_neighbor_4
   230                                         
   231  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124938                   VIS = VIS + flux_neighbor_VIS
   232  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB      124938                   IR = IR + flux_neighbor_IR
   233                                         
   234  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               Sol = cos_Illumination[facet_i] * F * inv_dH_sqr * (1
   235  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                       - albedo)
   236  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               SH = (VIS + IR) * (1 - albedo)
   237  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               Flux = Sol + SH
   238  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1               file.write(' %5.5f %5.5f %5.5f %5.5f %5.5f \n' % (Flux,
   239  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1                          Sol, SH, VIS, IR))
   240                                         
   241                                                 # # geometry of illumination of facets contributing to selfheating of our facet
   242                                                 #     for y in range(nb_facets_SH):
   243                                                 #         file2.write(" %2.5f %2.5f \n" % (cos_Illumination[facets_SH[y]], nb_node_Illumination[facets_SH[y]]))
   244                                         
   245                                                 # file2.close()
   246                                         
   247  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           file.close()
   248  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1           gc.collect()
   249                                             
   250  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       cos_Illumination = None
   251  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       del cos_Illumination
   252  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       nb_node_Illumination = None
   253  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       del nb_node_Illumination
   254  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       interval = time.time() - start_time
   255  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       print ('Total time in min:', interval / 60)
   256  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       ctypes._reset_cache()
   257  179.820 MiB    0.000 MiB           1       gc.collect()
```

Any hints ?

Edit:
Code
pastebin.com/N76eXu2w & pastebin.com/m2dT4CyQ

Comment: It doesn't sound like a leak.  As long as the objects have references they won't be freed.  If multiple calls don't accumulate, the previous object referenced is being release when it is assigned a new object.

Comment: I agree on the logic. But the profiler is showing otherwise, memory is accumulating. Simply seeing resource monitor, showing memory eaten like 0.1 Mb per second in my machine.

Comment: Variables that seem to leak are ndpointer(ctypes.c_float) and
   ndpointer(ctypes.c_int) which are pointers that I cannot free in C library because I am using them in each iteration.

Comment: You should post how you're using the function, how you create the objects, the *Illuminate* code, ...., and so on. That's a [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, not sure how does *CTypes* handles *NumPy* *argtypes*.

Comment: I think you may have confused some of us with "Result is not cumulative so Memory allocation must not be cumulative."  I, at least, first took that as a statement that you *do not* see memory usage increases persisting after the called native function returns, but I now suspect that you mean something altogether different.

Comment: Are you confident that the native function is not leaking?  Have you tested that separately from Python with an appropriate tool, such as valgrind?

Comment: In the same vein, do you see similar behavior if you substitute a do-nothing function with the same signature in place of `Illumination()`?

Comment: I meant: results for each iteration are not used again. It is not something to mention probably you are right, as the algorithm speaks of itself. So I meant to my understanding, memory must not cumulate. In reality it is cumulating.

Comment: And, last question for now, If you call `Illumination()` twice in a row, with (only) a `gc.collect()` between, do you see twice the increase in memory usage?

Comment: 1)) I run again with same parameters, but empty C library. Memory does not add. So I am suspecting again C function's parameters. All other variables are freed except parameters. 2)) with only Python code allocating parameters but no C call at all: memory doesn't add. 3)) with gc.collect() between two calls: it adds few MBs less than 25 the first, while GC collects some 0.2MBs this is bizarre, it will lead an out of memory but it says something.

Comment: I just figured other posts suggesting to comeback to C just after utilisation before loop end, to free memory like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14944367/ctypes-segfault-on-osx-only the problem is that I couldn't make a return instead of parameters like examples

Comment: @Curcuma_ It seems like the link gives you the answer assuming you have access to the C source code for your Illumination library (and assuming that the Illumination function call allocates the memory for both `fact_sun` and `nb_nodes`).  If so, you should add a C function to which you pass a pointer that calls `free()` on that pointer, and then call it from python at the end of each loop iteration, once for each of `fact_sun` and `nb_nodes`.

Comment: @Curcuma_ Since you mentioned your C knowledge is basic, if you post the Illumination C code, I can post an example with the necessary free function and how to call it.

Comment: thanks Turix, I post it in Pastebin in two links. I implemented the free_memory callback and it is receiving the same address. Finally the leak is probably somewhere else. I know the file opening in both C and Python is not the best way possible. I should mention also that testing Python alone, and lib.Illumination alone does not seem to leak. One last thing, as opposed to what I said earlier, each iteration stack like 1 to 2 MB and not 25 MB (that was the first iteration only). Still, It is very consuming with the available resources.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/N76eXu2w & https://pastebin.com/m2dT4CyQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for posting the pastebin links.  I see there that you have already attempted to change the `Illumination()` function to return the `fact_sun` pointer instead of passing it as an argument.  I also see the `free_mem()` function you may have also added. I will suggest an answer based on this version.

It looks like the `free_mem()` function is being used correctly for the `cos_Illumination` pointer in your python code. However, it appears you have a slight mistake in your implementation of `free_mem()` in C that will make a big difference.  On line 576 of your second pastebin link, it should be `if (fact_sun)` and not `if (!fact_sun)`.  In other words, you want to free the memory if the pointer has a value (i.e., it's not NULL), not when it doesn't have a value.  (I assume you were not seeing any output from the `printf` statement you have there when it's inside the `if` block... which is anyway incorrect, by the way:  it should be `printf("%p\n", (void * )fact_sun);` without the `&`.)

Note that, strictly speaking, the check for NULL in `free_mem()` shouldn't be necessary anyway, as freeing a NULL pointer is supposed to be nop according the the C standard.  (In fact, your code is relying on that elsewhere given that it only allocates and assigns slots `1` through `N_Node` and `N_Face` of several of the vectors, but frees slots `0` through `N_Node` and `N_Face`.)  But I personally think it's probably still a good idea to check it, as I have seen older instances of C compilers that have issues with freeing a NULL pointer.

While setting `fact_sun` to NULL there isn't necessary either (as `fact_sun` is just a local variable and so goes out of scope when the function returns), that practice *would* be a good idea for each and all of the *global* variables that are being freed in the other `free_memory()` function.  However, does not appear to be a source of problems for the code as it currently stands.

So overall, it becomes:

```
// free memory of variable returned to python
void free_mem(double * fact_sun) {
  if (fact_sun) {
    printf("%p\n", (void * )fact_sun);
    free(fact_sun);
  }
}
```

Finally, although it's probably not a big deal (as long as the pointer is NULL), it looks like you do not need the `free(nb_nodes)` on line 380 of your second pastebin link (since you never allocate it, unless there's more code that you didn't include).

Comment: valuable! yes I successfully implemented free_mem on one variable among the two that I think are the biggest. Now free_mem in my linux distribution one some iterations bizzarly yields this error: `double free or corruption (out)` `Abandon (core dumped)`. On a Mac OS it doesn't give an error. I found somewhere that the proper way is to set the variable to NULL even after freeing it, this is why I test it's Nullity before although the whole thing seems bizarre for me as it's the same adress and should be maintained without fearing a memory leak.

Comment: and why would it have the same address anyway ? as the variable is reallocated each time `double * fact_sun = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * nb_pts)`

Comment: @Curcuma_  Regarding your second question, it's probably because of the `&` you are using in your printf call.  (The one I suggested you remove in my answer.) With the `&` there, you print the _address_ of the `fact_sun` pointer, which is the address on the stack where the variable is held, not the contents of the (pointer) variable.  That will often be the same across multiple calls to a function.

Comment: @Curcuma_ The "double free" message is concerning -- even if it's not reported on Mac, the Linux report should not be ignored.  I did not see any double frees in the code you posted to pastebin, although you can help prevent them by adding the NULL assignments in the `free_memory()` method (as suggested in the fourth paragraph of my answer).

Comment: Now I see it works better on Mac OS with your free implementation with much much more iterations that's great already! sadly I couldn't get Valgrind set correctly on Mac (setup stuff). I am manually checking other variables in Illumination lib for some other leaks.

Comment: @Curcuma_ That's great.  If you know how to use valgrind on Linux, it would be very useful to find out where the double free is happening.  (The fix will be the same for both Linux and Mac, so you can just debug/diagnose the problem on Linux.)

Comment: Kindly, see the attached report of Valgrind https://pastebin.com/tGPxmRB5 note that on Mac it turns well with free but I couldn't set-up Valgrind

Comment: here is the visualizer I am using on the version without free at all. https://pasteboard.co/JGZvxyN.png

Comment: OK, I see another problem.  In the pastebin link to your Illumination C code, on line 383, `Face[m]` is being freed within a for-loop that ranges up to `N_Node`, but it was only allocated up to `N_Face` in the loop that starts on line 479.  So you need to move line 383 into the loop that starts on line 377 instead.  If this isn't clear, let me know and I'll add the updated code in my answer above.

Comment: Fixed that, with also setting each freed variable to NULL as you suggested earlier, Valgrind is still showing the same memory growth.

Comment: @Curcuma_ I went ahead and made the fixes (as well as adding code to nullify all pointers being freed in `free_memory()`) shown here: 
 https://pastebin.com/DsbRGbVt

Comment: kind of you the `FREE_NULLIFY` I will let it run on MAC for few hours and see where it goes. note that setting the free_mem correctly, execution jumped from 6k to 113k which is a huge gain !! the algorithm as set, should go for millions of iterations. do you have any thoughts on C file input output inside a loop? in Python as I saw, it is just normal with a proper `with open()` statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226509/discussion-between-curcuma-and-turix).

Comment: For follow readers: After chat with Turix, a proper allocation in one separate function for global variables when possible instead of local variables; and one separate function to free all global variables. also after spotting one error freeing one big matrix, (an error in dimensions) and finally properly implementing the callback function that frees particularly the returned value, leak is no longer present, so this was the nice solution for my problem

Answer (score 1):

A tool that is particularly helpful in the case that you are using both Python and C++ is https://github.com/vmware/chap because it understands both allocations in python arenas and allocations done using libc malloc.  The tool is open source and runs on Linux.

In your case, what I would do is the following:

From the shell prompt:

```
echo 0x37 >/proc/<pid-of-your-process>/coredump_filter
```

Gather a core for your process using gcore.

Wait one minute or so.

Gather another core for your process using gcore.

Open each core in chap and do the following at the chap command prompt:

```
redirect on
describe used
describe leaked
summarize used
```

If you have an actual leak, where allocations are becoming unreachable, the output of "describe leaked" will reflect that.

If you simply have container growth, where some container is continually growing, you should be able to see that pretty quickly by comparing the output of "describe used" for the two cases.  You can identify some kind of object that appears much more in the second core, pick one of these, and use chap on the second core to understand why it is held.

Comment: I successfully run chap on both outputs,I am trying to find differences. My question is: can one single output say something about memory leaks because both are very long. Kindly, here is one output, if you mind a Cntl-F for some known issues ? https://pastebin.com/KyTjBycJ

Comment: The very last line gives overall counts.  For example, the file for that pastebin.com URL shows

Comment: ... 2051 allocations use 0x413b0 (267,184) bytes.

Comment: The fact that the total leak count is less than a megabyte and you are getting 25+MB growth per each call of one function means that, although leaks are still of interest, your bigger cause of growth is related to some containers getting large.

Comment: Based on the attached output, it appears to be the result of "describe leaked".   It definitely makes sense to look at that further, but first can you post those trailing lines (with "allocations use") from the ends of the outputs of "describe used" on the two cores?

Comment: Also, can you verify that you set the coredump_filter for your process to 0x37?

Comment: With respect to the leaks, your next step might be to use the following command: "describe unreferenced /extend ~> /commentExtensions true /redirectSuffix leakedFromUnreferenced" because that command will structure things so that it shows for every "unreferenced allocation" (not referenced anywhere) which leaked allocations are reachable by a sequence of one or more references from that allocation.

Comment: `core.pid.describe_used` is huge and the last line is : "610371 allocations use 0x26150c8 (39,932,104) bytes." which is 39 MB

Comment: here is the output of leakedFromUnreferenced: https://pastebin.com/qFQS3Vyz I am so sorry as I am no longer able to follow, but I will try.

Comment: https://github.com/vmware/chap/blob/master/USERGUIDE.md has documentation about what an "unreferenced" allocation is, and how an unreferenced allocation is a special case of a "leaked" allocation.   It also describes what the /extend switch does.   The output that you just attached shows at the start, instances of python str, that look like documentation to me.   My general experience is that if such strings are reported as leaked, this generally means that the coredump_filter for the process was not set to 0x37.

Comment: The issue is that recent versions of gdb will often omit static writable regions associated with shared libraries, unless bit 2 of the coredump_filter for the process is set.   As a result, any allocations solely referenced by these shared libraries will be falsely reported as leaked, because the referencing regions are not present in the core.

Comment: In any case, I think the first focus should be on container growth, given that the total leaked bytes are two orders of magnitude smaller than the total used bytes.  Assuming that you did "describe used" on both cores, it would be interesting to see the last line of the output of the other "describe used", just so you can see how the bytes for used allocations changed between the two cores.   Another thing that would be useful to look at will be to do "diff" on the two outputs of "describe used".

Comment: Once you have the results of the "diff" you can just read through some of it to see what the most common things are that were added, then pick one added allocation and use "describe incoming <address>" repeatedly to see how that allocation is held.